# java application to have translation files like android has

Tags: java, internationalization, translation

I need JAVA application to have translation files like android has. 
Some easy framework to maintain different languages and to be able to swap then on ease.

ed: it is desktop application...

Comment: did you try google?  the first hit is the oracle tutorial on this very topic.

Comment: @Larva - Nah Google has entertained me for too long to be deemed such. Google ain't Goldilocks, but it aint Voldemort eother? somewhere in between I guess? SOMEWHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you do not have to call any constructor in order to switch language at runtime. In Java Desktop applications it is as ease as:

```
Locale brazilian = new Locale("pt", "BR");
Locale.setDefault(brazilian);
```

Of course if you want to switch it via JComboBox, you would probably do it a bit different. What I would do, I would actually create Model (Swing promotes MVC Design Pattern) that will hold data (different Locales) and I would set default Locale in correct ActionListener. It is not easy though.

Of course I would rather use native names for Locales. If you have them constructed, you can easily get native name Locale name by simply calling getDisplayName() passing itself as a parameter:

```
String brazilianNativeName = brazilian.getDisplayName(brazilian);
```

The result might be unsatisfactory for certain Locales (I believe Brazilian Portuguese is unfortunately one of them), but there is not much you can do about it (unless you use your own string).

To be honest, for just two languages, I would probably use some links instead. You can use simple JLabels to do that, just set correct font properties and color and assign common ActionListener. You can then query which one was actually clicked and create and set Locale appropriately. For homework that should be sufficient.

Comment: so where do I put translated strings to appear when people changes the locale?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Should be sufficient for my project.